# Java 11 issue Getting Unmarshalling Error while passing invalid date 2020-11-31 but not in java8

Tags: java, soap, soapui, java-11, datetimeformatter

```
  <accountLastUpdatedDate>2020-11-31T00:00:00</accountLastUpdatedDate>
```

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: "2020-11-31T00:00:00" is not a valid representation of an XML Gregorian Calendar value.</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In java8 date is incremented to the next date. Hence, It will become 1-dec-2020

Comment: The [`LocalDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` and all predefined pattern constants have [`ResolverStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) as `STRICT`. Either marshal/serialize a correct date (Nov has only 30 days) or use a custom pattern with `DateTimeFormatter` to unmarshal it. A custom `DateTimeFormatter` has by default `ResolverStyle` as `SMART`.

Comment: Can you please show your Java code? Also as I see it the problem is with Java 8. It should not accept an invalid date.

Comment: I may have reproduced. On my Java 8 `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2020-11-31T00:00:00")` yields an `XMLGregorianCalendar` of the invalid date `2020-11-31T00:00:00` (so not 1 December!). On Java 11 it throws with an exception message similar to yours.

Comment: How is this related to the tool [tag:sopaui]?